# How to handle the claims about delay in my assigned work area, when my boss is not reporting / managing properly?

Tags: raise, brazil

I'm from Brazil

Sorry for the bad English and bad word choices.

Here where I work, it's me a SQL Server DBA and there's a Senior Oracle DBA ( my boss ) and many other people but I'm focusing on me and my boss.

Since i'm here for 2 years, and i know my salary is really lower than other companies, I asked for a raise ( not for my boss, but for his boss, that is the leader of the company, hes really friendly ).

We work here with tickets, and I can solve them really fast, doing a great job, helping everyone with their tasks even if it's not about database, I really like to help people and everyone here knows it and people likes my job. )

I try to help everyone with oracle too, because my boss just do nothing unless the owner of the company calls him and destroy him telling that he does nothing, then for 1 or 2 days he does some work, and again, start doing nothing, but that not of my business, I really don't care.

Anyways, after asking about the raise, brad ( the boss of IT area ( hes the son of the company's owner, it's a mess here )) he said " oh well there are some taks in oracle that is taking to much time to be solved. I see you take some time solving that issues and etc. I told him that I don't even know about those tasks, because people ask my boss ( senior oracle )to do it, then after some time they tell be "hey, can you help us here because he's doing nothing and don't care helping us" and then I say "of course what's the problem" and we solve the ticket.

my point is, is this right? to punish me because my boss does nothing he's responsible too?

Comment: Who is punishing you?  All I hear you describe are people asking for their ticket to be resolved.

Comment: How are you being punished?  And by who?

Comment: I understand that OP has been denied a raise because of the long time he takes to solve tickets that are his boss' responsibility.

Comment: Thanks laurent that's exactly the problem.

Comment: Your English is almost perfect. Just sayin'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *my point is, is this right? to punish me because my boss does nothing he's responsible too?*

**Absolutely not.**

One thing happened for good after the conversation with *Brad*, you got to know that the tracking system is either non-existent or non-functioning. There is no report for your great performance which reaches the appropriate authority.

You need to have a talk with your immediate boss, inform him about the issue and try to find out a way that helps you claim the result of your good work. There can be two ways

1. Your boss in intentionally downplaying you - to prevent himself from looking bad
2. He is simply too lazy to appreciate the effort you put for your job, and then some extra efforts.

Either of the cases, your achievements should be visible in a proper way - you need to take a step towards making that possible now.

Comment: I might add that a poor tracking system hurts your users and your company as well as your personal reputation.  I will also add that top shelf DBAs who get things done are very valuable co-workers in many organizations.

Answer (score 1):

By starters you need to stop doing your boss job, you took reponsibility for the previous tickets so it is percived as your own failure you cannot change that but from now on you need to stop helping others you can use an easy excuse such as "my boss has expertise on this subject I cannot help you" etc